# Reduce an array into a single integer causes type error

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, type-conversion, reduce

I'm trying to take an array of Pairs(StartTime:Int, EndTime:Int) and reduce them to the accumulation of time for each session.

```
fun main() {
    val sessionsInSecond = listOf<Pair<Int,Int>>(Pair(10,12), Pair(10,15))

    val timeSpan: Int = sessionsInSecond.reduce{acc, it -> acc + (it.second - it.first) }
    println(timeSpan)
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable
>   because of receiver type mismatch: @InlineOnly public inline operator
>   fun BigDecimal.plus(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
>   @InlineOnly public inline operator fun BigInteger.plus(other:
>   BigInteger): BigInteger defined in kotlin public operator fun 
>   Array.plus(elements: Array): Array defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun  Array.plus(elements:
>   Collection): Array defined in kotlin.collections public
>   operator fun  Array.plus(element: Int): Array defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun BooleanArray.plus(element:
>   Boolean): BooleanArray defined in kotlin.collections public operator
>   fun BooleanArray.plus(elements: BooleanArray): BooleanArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun BooleanArray.plus(elements:
>   Collection): BooleanArray defined in kotlin.collections
>   public operator fun ByteArray.plus(element: Byte): ByteArray defined
>   in kotlin.collections public operator fun ByteArray.plus(elements:
>   ByteArray): ByteArray defined in kotlin.collections public operator
>   fun ByteArray.plus(elements: Collection): ByteArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections @InlineOnly public inline operator fun
>   Char.plus(other: String): String defined in kotlin.text public
>   operator fun CharArray.plus(element: Char): CharArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun CharArray.plus(elements:
>   CharArray): CharArray defined in kotlin.collections public operator
>   fun CharArray.plus(elements: Collection): CharArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun DoubleArray.plus(element:
>   Double): DoubleArray defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun
>   DoubleArray.plus(elements: DoubleArray): DoubleArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun DoubleArray.plus(elements:
>   Collection): DoubleArray defined in kotlin.collections public
>   operator fun FloatArray.plus(element: Float): FloatArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun FloatArray.plus(elements:
>   FloatArray): FloatArray defined in kotlin.collections public operator
>   fun FloatArray.plus(elements: Collection): FloatArray defined
>   in kotlin.collections public operator fun IntArray.plus(element: Int):
>   IntArray defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun
>   IntArray.plus(elements: IntArray): IntArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun IntArray.plus(elements:
>   Collection): IntArray defined in kotlin.collections public
>   operator fun LongArray.plus(element: Long): LongArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun LongArray.plus(elements:
>   LongArray): LongArray defined in kotlin.collections public operator
>   fun LongArray.plus(elements: Collection): LongArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun ShortArray.plus(element:
>   Short): ShortArray defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun
>   ShortArray.plus(elements: ShortArray): ShortArray defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun ShortArray.plus(elements:
>   Collection): ShortArray defined in kotlin.collections public
>   operator fun String?.plus(other: Any?): String defined in kotlin
>   public operator fun String?.plus(other: Any?): String defined in
>   kotlin public operator fun  Collection.plus(elements:
>   Array): List defined in kotlin.collections public
>   operator fun  Collection.plus(elements: Iterable):
>   List defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun 
>   Collection.plus(elements: Sequence): List defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun 
>   Collection.plus(element: Int): List defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun 
>   Iterable.plus(elements: Array): List defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun 
>   Iterable.plus(elements: Iterable): List defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun 
>   Iterable.plus(elements: Sequence): List defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun  Iterable.plus(element:
>   Int): List defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun  Map.plus(pairs: Array>): Map defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun  Map.plus(pair: Pair): Map defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun  Map.plus(pairs: Iterable>): Map defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun  Map.plus(map: Map): Map defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun  Map.plus(pairs: Sequence>): Map defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun  Set.plus(elements:
>   Array): Set defined in kotlin.collections public
>   operator fun  Set.plus(elements: Iterable): Set
>   defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun 
>   Set.plus(elements: Sequence): Set defined in
>   kotlin.collections public operator fun  Set.plus(element:
>   Int): Set defined in kotlin.collections public operator fun 
>   Sequence.plus(elements: Array): Sequence defined in
>   kotlin.sequences public operator fun  Sequence.plus(elements:
>   Iterable): Sequence defined in kotlin.sequences public
>   operator fun  Sequence.plus(elements: Sequence):
>   Sequence defined in kotlin.sequences public operator fun 
>   Sequence.plus(element: Int): Sequence defined in
>   kotlin.sequences

Any suggestions how to solve this?
ps. It's an exercise in reduce so i don't want to just add the values in a forEach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your result should be an `Int` here? You can change this to `fold` to make it work with little effort:

```
val timeSpan: Int = sessionsInSecond.fold(0) { acc, it -> 
    acc + (it.second - it.first) 
}
```

You start with `0` and continue adding to it until all values have been visited.
The problem in your code is that `acc` is of type `Pair<Int,Int>` rather than `Int`

Comment: This made sense.
Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

`acc` in reduce is `Pair<Int, Int>` in your case. You could either use `fold` or something like that

```
    val timeSpan = sessionsInSecond.reduce { acc, it ->
        acc.first + (it.second - it.first)
        acc
    }.first
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define an extension function on `Pair<Int, Int>` too. Giving it a typealias makes the code even more readable.

```
typealias SecondsInterval = Pair<Int, Int> 

fun SecondsInterval.diff() = second - first

val timeSpan = sessionsInSecond.sumBy(SecondsInterval::diff)
```

This becomes especially handy, if you want to retrieve the difference of a single `SecondsInterval` somewhere else.

```
val interval: SecondsInterval = 5 to 12
interval.diff() // 7
```